# spring security | security config permitall not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

@EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("user").roles("USER").build());
    return manager;
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
}
```

Above code is not working, url: localhost:8080/css/styles.css is redirecting to login page. 
The code layout is, src/main/resources/static folder has html, css and js folders inside of which files remain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of `WebMvcConfigurer `.

Answer (score 3):

I think **addResourceHandlers** method can help you.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

 @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
 }
}
```

it means find your resources in your static folder.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work, but currently in my project, this is my config. and it's working properly.

```
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/js/**", "/css/*", "/images/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        }
```